# Cucumber 7 tags understanding

Tags: selenium, cucumber, bdd, cucumber-java

Recently upgraded to Cucumber 7 and upon trying to run by tags as

```
mvn clean test -D"cucumber.filter.tags=@regression and not @slow and not @exclude and not @legacy"
```

and upon checking report, some features were not picked up

```
Example
@payrules @clean
Feature: xxxxxxxxxx

@regression
Scenario: xxxxxxx
Given xxxxxx
And xxxxxxxxx
```

upon reading https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/api/?sbsearch=tag&lang=java#tags, this scenario should be picked up, but yet got skipped

did something changed and only one set of tags can be set on scenario or feature level?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this. Do simpler expressions work as expected?

Comment: tags look good, cant see any problem

Comment: yet, scenario is not being picked up

Comment: yet when I add extra tag on scenario level beside regression and in command add - regression and @tag and not.. , feature is being picked up

Comment: Can you make a MCVE based on https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton and use that to submit a bug report to https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm

Answer (score 0):

Please move the double quotes after cucumber.filter.tags:
`mvn clean test -Dcucumber.filter.tags="@regression and not @slow and not @exclude and not @legacy"`

Comment: did not made a difference, still not being picked up